# Save selected D3.js Treemap nodes to local file

Tags: html, d3.js

I am trying to finalize a D3.js treemp using this example code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I am running a local "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" web instance to serve up my pages.

I am not proficient in HTML or JavaScript.

I have a very large local JSON file that I created in python that is referenced in the "d3.json("d3_flare.json", function(error, flare)" in the index.html code snippet.

I need assistance with two items please:

1. I have very long text on the 4th node down from the JSON root node that D3.js & HTML will process. The text looks like:

"name": "Some Title:  Some very very long text...Some very very long text...Some very very long text...Some very very long text...Some very very long text."

but can be longer or shorter.

How can I wrap this text to be more legible and neat while viewing in the browser at this position of JSON being read by D3.js & HTML given my attached index.html code snippet?

2. I need to save every selected node path(s) to a local file (e.g. CSV) that the user has clicked on, remember only running a local "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" web instance to serve up my pages.

How can I write the selected node paths to a local file given my attached index.html code snippet?

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

/*var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
*/

var margin = {top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 40, left: 500},
    width = 10000 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 775 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("d3_flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth original was 180
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 900; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think I have a solution for my first question of two by using a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674371/d3-horizontal-tree-layout-with-rect-and-text-wrapping

Comment: I still need help with my second question please. How do I save selected nodes to local file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my second question I ended up adding a contextmenu to the var nodeEnter section of my previously posted code where users are directed only to right-click a certain node in the path that gets recorded. The contextmenu:

```
.on("contextmenu", function (d) {
d3.event.preventDefault()
sessionStorage.setItem("selected_node", JSON.stringify(d.name));
var val = sessionStorage.getItem("selected_node");
post_session(val);
});
```

I then passed the sessionStorage objects to this function where I have cgi/bin python writing the requests to a file:

```
function post_session(session_store_info)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', 'cgi-bin/post_session', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
    http.send(session_store_info);
    return http.status!=404;
}
```